# View filtered by node value NOT IN another view?

Tags: entities, views

I'd like to create a view for a CCK type, and show nodes of which the value does not exist in the result of another view.

For example, I have `Student` and `Attendance` CCK types, I'd like to list all the students who are not shown in the `Attendance` nodes.

Both CCK types shared the same `student_id` CCK field.